# How to set up a Graphic Designer to work on Asp.Net MVC 3 Razor Views?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

We have graphic designers that work on the "look & feel" of our web applications. They typically work with HTML, CSS & images. How can we set up a designer's development environment to work with TFS, Asp.Net MVC 3 Razor Views? What would be the best workflow for them?

We want them to be able to check out the views / css from TFS, edit them, view the results and then check back into TFS.

How can they see their changes to views & css if they don't have the full Visual Studio or IIS or IIS Express?

Should we periodically deploy a web application to a web server for them to work on?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can download Visual Web Developer Express for free. Once they get that, they can run the project locally (assuming they have access to the database if there is one).

I'm not sure if the TFS plugin is free, if it is then they can work with source control.